# @QuarkusIntegrationTest : Unable to determine the status of the running process. See the above logs for details

Tags: quarkus

I'm currently learning Quarkus and I have an issue with Native testing.

In this repository (the **dev** branch), I can package into JAR and binary and run them ([AdinhLux/quarkus-1-intro][https://github.com/AdinhLux/quarkus-1-intro/tree/dev]).

I'm just encountering an issue when running the below command line. It seems my Maven was looking for an information into **.target/quarkus.log** but nothing is written.

```
mvn verify -Pnative

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running org.agoncal.quarkus.starting.BookResourceIT
Jul 20, 2022 4:48:58 PM org.jboss.threads.Version <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Threads version 3.4.2.Final
Executing "/Users/adinhlux/development/IntelliJProjects/rest-book/target/rest-book-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner -Dquarkus.http.port=8081 -Dquarkus.http.ssl-port=8444 -Dtest.url=http://localhost:8081 -Dquarkus.log.file.path=/Users/adinhlux/development/IntelliJProjects/rest-book/target/quarkus.log -Dquarkus.log.file.enable=true"
Waited 60 seconds for target/quarkus.log to contain info about the listening port and protocol but no such info was found
[ERROR] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 61.737 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.agoncal.quarkus.starting.BookResourceIT
[ERROR] org.agoncal.quarkus.starting.BookResourceIT.shouldCountAllBooks  Time elapsed: 0.012 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to determine the status of the running process. See the above logs for details
```

I'm running my project on macOS Monterey M1 with the following settings :

```
sdk install java 17.0.4-oracle
brew install --cask graalvm/tap/graalvm-ce-java17
sdk install maven 3.8.6
sdk install quarkus 2.10.2.Final


xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java17-22.1.0/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
cd $JAVA_HOME/bin
gu install native-image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue .

In application.properties you need this :

```
quarkus.log.category."org.agoncal".level=DEBUG
```